# cannot read the properties of undefined 'highest'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to check if the mentioned member role is in the same position as the bot or higher, but I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'highest')
```

**My code**:

```js
            const member = message.mentions.users.first();
            const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') || 'No reason specified.'

            if (member.roles.highest.position >= message.guild.client.roles.highest.position) return message.reply('I cannot moderate this user as their highest role is higher than mine or I have the same highest role position as them.')
```

I am using discord.js v13.8.0 and Node.js v16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to remember that in Discord (and, consequently, Discord.js), `User`s are absolutely not the same as `Member`s. `message.mentions.users.first();` returns a [`User` object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User), which doesn't have any property named `roles`.

You seem to want the [`members` property on `message.mentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) instead, which returns a Collection of [`GuildMember` objects](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember), each of which *should* have the `roles` property:

```
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') || 'No reason specified.'

if (member.roles.highest.position >= message.guild.client.roles.highest.position) return message.reply('I cannot moderate this user as their highest role is higher than mine or I have the same highest role position as them.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using assigning a `User` to `member`, and `message.guild.client` returns a `Client` object, which does not have `.roles`. Use `.mentions.members` and `.guild.me` instead

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') || 'No reason specified.'

if (member.roles.highest.position >= message.guild.me.roles.highest.position) return message.reply('...')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `message.guild.client`, you get the client which instantiated the guild and it doesn't have a `roles` property. Instead you can use:

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
const botMember = message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id)
const reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') || 'No reason specified.'

if (member.roles.highest.position >= botMember.roles.highest.position) return message.reply('I cannot moderate this user as their highest role is higher than mine or I have the same highest role position as them.')
```