# How to check if bot has higher role than mentioned user

Tags: discord.js

I'm making a bot that's gonna have a few moderator commands. I need to check if the bot has a higher role than the tagged user.

My code:

```
        let mentionedRole = message.mentions.members.first().roles.highest
        let botRole = client.user.roles.highest

        if (mentionedRole.position > botRole.position) {
            message.channel.send(`I dont have access to mute this member.${message.author}`)
            return
        }
```

The error shown:

> let botRole = client.user.roles.highest

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'highest')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot read the properties of undefined 'highest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71785386/cannot-read-the-properties-of-undefined-highest)

Comment: `User`s don't have roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this (at least in my own opinion) would I think be easier, I would do this:

```js
if (!message.mentions.members.first().manageable) {
    // above if statement determines whether the client user is above this user in the hierarchy, according to role position and guild ownership.
    message.channel.send(`I dont have access to mute this member.${message.author}`)
    return
}
```

[Discord.JS](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=manageable)